# MatterJS static angle

Tags: javascript, game-physics, matter.js

Is it possible to "lock" the angle of a MatterJS body, so that it will never change, even when collisions would usually cause it to. I don't mind whether it is able to be changed manually or not, I just don't want collisions, friction or velocity to affect it.

Answer (score 2):

Developers recommend setting inertia of a body to Infinity to prevent it from rotating, make sure to do it with Matter.Body.setInertia(), instead of setting it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution (in terms of performance), but I solved this issue by doing this:

```
Matter.Events.on(engine, "beforeTick", function () {
    Matter.Body.setAngularVelocity(staticAngleBody, 0);
});
```